# Executor service invocation within streams

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream, executorservice

I'm faced with compile-time errors when using Executor service within streams. (There are alternative ways but I wanted to check if this is possible)

```
class Operation implements Callable<Integer> {

    int i; int j;
    Operation(int i, int j) { this.i = i; this.j = j; }

    @Override
    public Integer call()  {
        return integerOps(i, j); //integerOps throws MyException
    }

}

// somewhere within main method

total = IntStream
    .range(1,100)
    .boxed()
    .map(t -> executor.submit(new Operation(t, FACTOR) )) // -> COMPILE TIME ERROR 
    .map(t -> {
        try {
            return t.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    })
    .mapToInt(t->t)
    .sum();
```

Case 1:

If `MyException` is `RuntimeException` (Unchecked) then the error is

> No enclosing instance of type `IterativeExecutionTechniques` is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type `IterativeExecutionTechniques` (e.g. `x.new A()` where `x` is an instance of `IterativeExecutionTechniques`).

**How to solve this without touching Operation class and how to cause the unchecked exception to break the execution and exit gracefully?**

Case 2:

If `MyException` is `Exception` (Checked) then the error is

> No enclosing instance of type `ExceptionHandling` is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type `ExceptionHandling` (e.g. `x.new A()` where `x` is an instance of `ExceptionHandling`).

**How to solve this without touching Operation class and how to handle the checked exception and continue the execution?**

Comment: That error message doesn't look like its related to `MyException`, but how `Operation` is being created. It's hard to tell because this looks like modified code, can you post the complete original code and error message?

Comment: You didn't post enough code for a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Anyhow, if what the compiler is saying surprises you, most probably one of your inner classes needs a `static` modifier (ie: `public class Foo{  static class Bar{ }  }`.

Comment: @giorgiga you are correct, Operation class needed to be static. But why is that a requirement here for class instantiation? Also, the error thrown doesn't make sense.

Comment: @John, why does the error make no sense to you?

Comment: @John non-static inner class instances hold an implicit reference to an instance of the "wrapping" class: inner classes are not just a namespacing thing.